# How do I test an app on my iPhone without an Apple Developer license?

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak

This has been answered many times before, but none of those answers are compatible with iOS 6. The only answers that mention iOS 6 use a tool called Jailcoder, which isn't working for me.

What I have tried:

- Create a fake code-sign certificate
- Modify SDKSettings.plist
- Used Jailcoder to patch Xcode as well as my project

I am using Xcode 4.5.1 and iOS 6.0.1. Note that Xcode 4.5.1 doesn't have an SDK specific for 6.0.1, but I don't think that makes a difference.

Comment: this is exactly the same for iOS 6 as all other recent iOS versions.  H2CO3's solution is what I've been using since iOS 2.2.1, I believe.

Comment: No, it isn't. With earlier versions, you could've done it by modifying a few plists.

Comment: Nope. Modifying plists is just what you have to do to let Xcode let you build without a code signature. For it to actually *run* on the device, it still needs to have a signature. A jailbroken phone doesn't need a **valid** signature, but it does require a signature. That's what `ldid` does, and has done for several iOS versions.  [See here for more on this](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Bypassing_iPhone_Code_Signatures), and notice that Option #3 no longer works (I thought it was longer than since 4.3, but I may be wrong on that).

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using a fake code-sign certificate.

Comment: Using a non-Apple certificate is an *alternative* to using `ldid`, as described in the link in my last comment.  But again, that's nothing new.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Jailbreak your device (seems you have already done this step).
2. Build the app in Xcode. Take the binary which is compiled for iOS, not the one for the simulator.
3. Use the [`ldid`](https://github.com/rpetrich/ldid) utility to fake codesign the binary:

   `ldid -S ~/Projects/Foo/Foo.app/Foo`
4. Copy the `.app` folder (the application bundle) to your device (for example, using SSH). Reload the list of apps (either restart SpringBoard or use the `uicache` utility on the device).
5. Profit.

Comment: Where is the `.app` saved? Is there any way to copy over the folder without SSH? Isn't there a simple Build and Run solution?

Comment: @duci9y No simple solution, sorry. This is unofficial, unsupported and thus requires hacking. Be happy it's at least possible. Or build the project on the device itself using an on-device toolchain. Then you can write a simple Makefile that installs the app directly after building.

Comment: There used to be a way to do that. :( I found the `.app`. Now, any other way to copy it over?

Comment: @duci9y wrap the process in a bost-build script for build and run ability

Answer (score 0):

there is a better and easier way to do this. 
Download the Jailcoder.app App and press "guided patch" or "quick patch". Then the app will do all work for you and you can directly choose your iphone from the xcode organizer. 
On the iPhone you need the cydia tweak AppSync for iOS 5.0+

Comment: Read my question. I already tried Jailcoder. And I have already solved my problem.