# Testing in a iOS 6.1 jailbroken device without Hackulo.us and Apple developer ID

Tags: ios, jailbreak

first of all, **I know there are many questions similar to this one**, but, they are old and the answers in them unfortunately no longer work, since the game has changed **without Hacklo.us** to do part of the process.

Basically, I want to develop for iOS and test the apps I make, and later in the future I may want to submit them to the Apple Store, but for now I'm not willing to pay 99$ to join the Apple iOS developer program just to use my apps in my iPhone.

I have a jailbroken iPhone 4S with iOS 6.1.

**The only posts I found about how to do this, either use Hackulo.us (that went down about 2 months ago) or something called Jailcoder that is also offline and they also seem to work with only old versions of XCode/iOS (not clear about that point).**

Any new progresses on how to to this with the present conditions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I test an app on my iPhone without an Apple Developer license?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536603/how-do-i-test-an-app-on-my-iphone-without-an-apple-developer-license)

Answer (score 1):

Simple. After building the app, just use some utility (SSH, iExplorer, etc.) to copy the app bundle to the /Applications directory on the device. After that, either run the `uicache` tool or respring the iPhone to make the application appear on the home screen.

Comment: Oh, that simple. I thought that wouldn't work without hackulo.us AppSync to allow that. I'll give it a try when I get home, thanks.

Comment: @jbssm If the app crashes upon launch: make sure the binary is executable (`chmod 755 <binary>`) and properly fake-codesigned (`ldid -S <binary>`).

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. And the fake-codesigning is a standard part of Cydia then, right? I'm just surprised how easy it seems after all the complicated stuff I read on how to do this.

Comment: @jbssm What do you mean by "it's a standard part of Cydia"?

Comment: That it's installed with my jailbreak by default, meaning I don't need to install an extra package in Cydia to use it.

Comment: @jbssm No, it isn't. Install `ldid` ("Link identity editor") from Cydia.

Comment: Well, I'm not being able to carry this out because XCode refuses to build the application for the device (it only builds it for the simulator) with the error: `The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains`